# build soapserver using codeigniter. url do not show wsdl file

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-services, nginx, wsdl

I'm new at this soap server. I user codeigniter to build a server web services. in my controller Serverservices.php i write

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
// turn off WSDL caching
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$server = new SOAPServer("http://web.mysite.com/assets/wsdl/test.wsdl");
$server->setClass('Serverservices');
$server->handle();

class Serverservices extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {}
    public function other() {}
}
?>
```

When i enter url http://web.mysite.com/serverservices?wsdl nothing happen. It do not show my wsdl file. But i can download my wsdl file if i access http://web.mysite.com/assets/wsdl/test.wsdl.

Any one can help? do i need to compile the wsdl? How can i compile the wsdl?

i use nginx on ubuntu 16.04 and php7.0

Comment: Seems like you like to punish yourself. Have you thought about using nusoap? https://www.sitepoint.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-1/

Answer (score 0):

Move your WSDL code inside the index method. You are only specifying a controller on the url but you have not specified a method so it will call index method by default.

```
class Serverservices extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

        $server = new SOAPServer("http://web.mysite.com/assets/wsdl/test.wsdl");
        $server->setClass('Serverservices');
        $server->handle();
    }

    public function other() {}
}
```

You can also use this library which [adds nuSoap to CodeIgniter](https://github.com/rusagar/soapserver_codeigniter)

Comment: hi i already did that but still nothing happen. I compare content-type in my localhost it is text/xml but in server it is text/html. Already add {text/xml wsdl} in my mime types

Comment: hmmm...did you try adding the dot after the question mark to your URL for file type? http://web.mysite.com/serverservices?.wsdl or maybe a more complete 'filename' http://web.mysite.com/serverservices?file.wsdl

Comment: already tried but nothing happen. i updated in the answer below the nginx log. do you have any resources to understand that log?

Answer (score 0):

I try to access http://web.mysite.com/serverservices?wsdl and it return nothing. i see in log it shows like this

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.72 - - [02/Feb/2018:10:36:46 +0700] "GET /assets/wsdl/test.wsdl HTTP/1.1" 200 11700 "-" "-" 0.001 req_body:"-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [02/Feb/2018:10:36:46 +0700] "GET /serverservices?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36" 0.223 req_body:"-"
```

I try to access directly http://web.mysite.com/assets/wsdl/test.wsdl and it return XML body and it show this in the log

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [02/Feb/2018:10:39:41 +0700] "GET /assets/wsdl/test.wsdl HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36" 0.000 req_body:"-"
```

I try to access http://web.mysite.com/serverservices?test.wsdl and it return nothing. i see in log it shows like this

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.72 - - [02/Feb/2018:10:43:50 +0700] "GET /assets/wsdl/test.wsdl HTTP/1.1" 200 11700 "-" "-" 0.000 req_body:"-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [02/Feb/2018:10:43:50 +0700] "GET /serverservices?test.wsdl HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36" 0.004 req_body:"-"
```

Anyone have resources to understand this log? Because i think from that log my soapserver is working fine. It tried to retrieve assets/wsdl/test.wsdl. But no XML body returned. Or anyone know how to setup php native soapserver with fast cgi? because the only difference between my local and server is nginx and fastcgi